# Paginar comentarios mysqli y JSON

Tags: php, json, mysqli, paginación

Tengo este código para paginar comentarios y respuestas pero no lo reconoce:
ListaDeComentarios.php:

```
require_once ("Conexion.php");

$memberId = 1;
$commentId = $_POST['comentario_id'];
$likeOrUnlike = 0;
if($_POST['like_unlike'] == 1)
{
$likeOrUnlike = $_POST['like_unlike'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM megusta_nomegusta WHERE comentario_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (! empty($row)) 
{
    $query = "UPDATE megusta_nomegusta SET like_unlike = " . $likeOrUnlike . " WHERE  comentario_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
} else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO megusta_nomegusta(member_id,comentario_id,like_unlike) VALUES ('" . $memberId . "','" . $commentId . "','" . $likeOrUnlike . "')";
}
mysqli_query($conn, $query);

respuesta JSON enviada desde el código php:

 function listComment() {
        $.post("ListaDeComentarios.php",
                  function (data) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            var comments = "";
                            var replies = "";
                            var item = "";
                            var parent = -1;
                            var results = new Array();

                            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
                            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

                            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                            {
                                var commentId = data[i]['comentario_id'];
                                parent = data[i]['parent_comentario_id'];

                                var obj = getLikesUnlikes(commentId);
```

Me gusta y no me gusta función Ajax:

```
function getLikesUnlikes(commentId)
            {
/*Llamamos al archivo php*/
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: 'Envio_MeGusta.php',
                    data: {comentario_id: commentId},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        totalLikes = data;
                    }

                });

}

Paginate:

(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    function log(d) {
        console.log(d);
    }

    //    $(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.pagination = function (options) {
        //        alert('prout');
        var paginationContainer = this,
            itemsPerPage,
            itemsToPaginate,
            defaults,
            settings,
            i,
            numberOfPaginationLinks;

        log(paginationContainer);

        defaults = {
            itemsPerPage: 5
        };

        settings = {};

        $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

        itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

        itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
        numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));
        log(numberOfPaginationLinks);

        // Création de list dans la div ciblée
        $('<ul></ul>').prependTo(paginationContainer);

        // Boucle qui créer des li
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfPaginationLinks; i += 1) {
            paginationContainer.find('ul').append('<li>' + (i + 1) + '</li>');
        }

        itemsToPaginate.filter(':gt(' + (itemsPerPage - 1) + ')').hide();

        paginationContainer.find('ul li').click(function () {

            var itemsToHide,
                linkNumber,
                itemsToShow,
                $this = $(this);

            $this.addClass(settings.activeClass);
            $this.siblings().removeClass(settings.activeClass);

            linkNumber = $this.text();

            itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(':lt(' + ((linkNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage) + ')');

            $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(':gt(' + ((linkNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1) + ')'));

            itemsToHide.hide();

            itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
            itemsToShow.show();

        });
    };
    //    });

}(jQuery));

custom.js:

(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Appel du plugin
        $('.pagination').pagination({
            itemsToPaginate: ".output",
            activeClass: 'active'
        });

    });

}(jQuery));

$('.pagination').pagination({

      itemsPerPage: 10 // default: 5
    });
```

Comment: Hola Alfredo, tal y como está redactada la pregunta no termina de quedar claro qué es lo que necesitas (¿ordenar los datos en casillas en el front end? ¿crear paginación?). Además de que haría falta más información: ¿cuál es el problema con el código compartido? (no parece estar relacionado con los problemas que describes después) ¿qué es lo que intentaste y qué errores recibiste? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Sería bueno que indicaras de dónde has sacado ese código, y deberías tener cuidado (y casi descartarlo) porque tiene problemas de seguridad graves (XSS), usa código anticuado (la etiqueta `center` está obsoleta), presenta código que no es accesible (label vacío) y en general es confuso (¿por qué los campos tienen mismo name si son diferentes?)...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro estaba buscando un sistema de comentarios + respuestas+ like + paginación. Encontre este pero no fui capaz de paginarlo : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175038/paginar-comentarios-y-respuestas. Seguí buscando y encontré este Ultimo de Tuntoriales pero no me gustaba el código css y al modificarlo dejo de funcionar... contacte con el propietario del sitio web https://www.baulphp.com/sistema-de-comentarios-php-me-gusta-y-no-me-gusta/ y solicite presupuesto para realizar la paginación pero me dijo que no hacían encargos..y asi llevo más de 2 meses. ¿Me puedes ayudar? gracias

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro este sistema que es el que me gusta https://www.baulphp.com/sistema-de-comentarios-php-me-gusta-y-no-me-gusta/ he intentado paginar con PDO, ajax, query, datatable..jPages-master .pero no doy con el punto exacto. Gracias por responder

Comment: Edita la pregunta para clarificarla. Lo que pone en la pregunta tiene poco que ver con lo que pones en los comentarios y el código no está relacionado en nada. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta en consecuencia.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he editado pregunta y puesto código a ver si ahora se entiende y disculpar mi ignorancia. Saludos

Comment: nadie sabe como arreglar? lo muevo a otro foro por si aquí no es el sitio correcto?

Comment: @Walter Cordova veo que has corregido , gracias ¿ves el fallo en el codigo?